# Can't access my local host via Google Chrome on Android

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

I have mini PC which serves as a small home server for various needs. Running Ubuntu 20.04.
When I replaced my old router with new one I'm having minor issues with connection:

- when trying to connect with server hostname (not ip) from W10 via ssh: works perfectly
- when trying to connect with server hostname from Windows 11 via Google Chrome: works perfectly
- when trying to connect from Android device (ssh and Google Chrome): got error that name can't be resolved

Tried flushing DNS records on the android device and setting custom DNS server (1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com), but with no avail. Connecting with IP works, but I would like to use server's hostname.
Any advice would be much appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure the new router has a DNS record for your server, and set the router as the DNS server for the Android device. Win10/11 will use mdns to discover hostnames on the local network, but I'm not sure Android does the same by default? might depend on the version/device